# Possibility to return to slide 1 when presention is idle for 30 seconds

Tags: powerpoint

For a project on a convention we are making a PowerPoint presentation where customers can navigate trough slides using a touch screen themselves, and it all works using actions and hyperlinks to get to the right slides etc. However, I would like the presentation to return to the first slide or the landing page if it hasn't been interacted with for for example 30 seconds. I know there is the possibility to move to the next slide after a said amount of time, but can you also make it go to a set slide after some time?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need.  I was able to figure out a workaround, although it seems to be the long way to do this.

1. Make sure "Use Timings" is checked on the Slide Show Tab.
2. On the Slide Show Tab, click "Create Custom Slide Show".
3. I created a new Custom Slide show by the following steps.
   a. Add all of the slides to the custom slide show.
   b. Then add Slide 1 (or whichever slide you prefer) after each of the
   slides in the custom slide show.
4. After saving the Custom Slide Show, go to the Transitions Tab.
5. On the right side of the Menu Bar, check the "After" box and set your
   timeout.
6. Click "Apply to All", but go to your "Home" slide and uncheck the
   "After" box.
7. Now go to the Slide Show Tab and click "Set Up Slide Show".  I chose
   Kiosk mode, but the main thing is to select "Custom Show" on the right
   hand side and choose your custom made slide show.

For my purposes, this worked for me, but keep in mind that the timer is not really an "Idle" timer.  The timer starts as soon as the slide appears.